# How do i get the answer of an equation in dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I would like to get the answer of the equation in double which is in string like "2+3*9". How can I do this with Dart?

Comment: Dart doesn't evaluate code provided at runtime. The code has to be available at compile time.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer That's most likely the topic of an homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stack Data Structure to calculate your expression. There are several rules that will be used while calculation using stack. 
Please try to google as it can explain you even batter how to use Stack for mathematical expression evaluation.

Or you can use [math_expressions](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/math_expressions) library for the same